# Is there any event or way exists in android to check if memory is low?

Tags: android

friends,

any one guide me if there is any event of useful way exits in android to know if my android application is running in low memory?

actually , i am caching many objects so i want to know a central place or area where i could release them if memory is low.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should change your accepted answer, mine is actually wrong -- application-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, see [onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory%28%29), Activity and others implement this.

edit: this is actually wrong, application-wise. See [Nik Reiman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564653/165164).

Comment: where to mention it? if i want to use it as a commonly? in my application? any idea

Comment: @UMAR maybe implementing it in a custom `Application` class. (sorry for late answer)

Answer (score 13):

Contrary to what @bigstones says, `onLowMemory()` doesn't exactly do what you would expect. My understanding of this call is that it is only reached when the *system* is low on memory and asks your application to free extra memory. `onLowMemory()` will never be called when the system has plenty of memory, but your app has reached its memory limit.

It's also a bad idea to try/catch the OutOfMemory exceptions. If you want to know your own app's memory usage, the best way to get it is via the [ActivityManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html), namely in the `getMemoryClass()` and `getProcessMemoryInfo()` methods.

Also, you should read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android) (from an Android engineer), which explains process memory use in a much more detailed way.

Answer (score 1):

OnLowMemory() only gets called when the system is running out of memory so with that you can implement following methods to check available memory before you decode the images.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Comment: This is a great hidden gem. i haven't seen it anywhere else yet `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();` gives me the actual bytes the OOM's reference to have free unlike all the others.